# User registration program for 10 users

Tags: c++

I am very new to coding and am trying to finish a simple system that manages user registration in C++ (using password hashing). I figured out how to store the usernames and passwords as was required per our instructor and am trying to figure out how to lock someone out after 3 failed attempts. In my code I have commented out code that I was trying to use to do this but I don't think will work. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to create a feature that locks someone out after 3 attempt's.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int returnVal(char x)
{
    return x - 96;

}

char usrname;



int main() {

    string name[10];
    int password[10];
    bool status[10];



    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)



    {
        //int count = 0;
        //for (;;)
        //{
            //ask_password();
            //if (password == expected_password)
                //break;
            //count++;
            //if (count == 3)
            //{
            //  Sleep(300000);    // 5 minutes = 300000 ms. 
            //  count = 0;
            //}
        }
        string s;

        cout << "Please Enter Username   " << endl << "Should you wish to stop entering user information enter 0:  ";
        cin >> name[index];

        if (name[index] == 0) {
            break;
        }

        cout << "Please Enter Password   ";
        cin >> s;

        cout << "Are you a regular user or an admin?  " << endl << "Enter 0 for a regular user and 1 for admin: ";
        cin >> status[index];




        int niffler = 0;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {

            niffler = niffler + returnVal(s[i]);
        }

        password[index] = niffler;

        cout << niffler;

        index++;
    }

    cout << "10 users have been created";


    // check username array for input
    // save where in the array we find the correct username
    // check password

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: We won't do your homework here. Your *fix-my-code* or *write-my-code* question is off-topic. Please think more. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the code formatting and indention.

Comment: You say you commented out the code to check for password but your instructor asked you (_clearing throat_... Agreeing with Basile, no one wants to do your homework for you) to lock a user after 3 failed login attempts. How is anyone meant to even begin helping when you're not even providing the code that checks for failure?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I'm feeling rather generous right this second. Was just going to do this in chat but I can't with you because your rep points are 1. Regardless, I'll *help* you with your homework (not do it for you). If anything that follows sounds terse it's certainly because I personally would expect better of anyone who was my student, regardless of level of experience.

First and foremost, what-in-the-name-of-spaghetti-monster is the following line of code in global scope used for?

```
char usrname;
```

Whatever it is, it can't be good. Speaking of not good. Am I to assume that your password "hash" function is the following (after I composited `returnValue()` with the "`niffler`" stuff?

```
int hashPassword(const std::string& password) {
    int hash = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != password.size(); ++i)
        hash += password[i] - 96;
    return hash;
}
```

That's not a hash function. If you do the math it means that the passwords "Pz" and "" are exactly the same (`0`). In fact, countless combinations of characters result in the exact same hash. At that point you might as well hold your nose and store the password directly because someone can brute-force the passwords (via hash collision) faster than they might get access to the actual passwords. Don't do that, but use a better hashing mechanism. I'd like to point you to the Wikipedia articles [Cryptographically secure hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and [Hash salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

The flow of what you're doing is incredible wrong. Your instructor asked you to allow ten people to log in correct? Why would ten people log in at the same time? Something tells me your instructor expects that you to *allow* for 10 people to log in, not necessarily all at the same time. Why would any program ask for 10 people to log in? Does Facebook or Twitter give you 10 login prompts?

Think of it more like a real-world program...

- You need a database of some form of at most 10 login entries including username, password hash, and access rights.
- Running the program allows the user to log in if they are in the database.
- If they fail at logging in, they should be locked out. *Aborting the program and simply letting them re-run it again to try again (as `sleep()` would let them do) does not count*.
- If they log in successfully, check their access credentials. Why would you ever ask a user if they're an administrator?

All of those are `if` conditions. Abstract that out a bit. Program like you're a program because you can't write software if you can't think like a computer.

For extra-credit, if they are an administrator, let them add, modify or delete the user records. The first (hardcoded) user is usually an admin and nearly always added by the programmer.